# Chrome in iPhone v/s Android

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, single-spa

We own a single-spa based PWA which works just fine on Android device chrome browser.

The same app fails to load in iPhone Chrome browser. However, it still works fine on Safari/Firefox.
Error is not descriptive enough:

```
LOGServiceWorker registration successful with scope: <url here>
ERRORSol module error!
ERRORModule NAME: @mst/auth
ERRORapplication '@mst/auth' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: (0,i.createContext) is not a function. (In '(0,i.createContext)(u.default)', '(0,i.createContext)' is undefined)
ERRORTypeError
```

This is not reproducible on Mac too.

Any leads/pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.